# Recording video in Python and storing it in any format until I press 'q' or 'Esc'

Tags: python, camera, video, raspicam

i have installed python3-picamera on raspberry pi and i want to record a video and store it in 
**.avi format untill i press "Esc" or 'q'.**
 I found below program but i don't want to use camera.wait_recording() in my program. I have tried using key = cv2.waitkey(1) & 0XFF, but didn't work. It is throwing

> syntax error: 'break' outside loop.

```
import time
import cv2   
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 360)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.start_recording('one_day.h264', quality=20, bitrate=750000)
    #camera.wait_recording(24 * 60 * 60)
    key = cv2.waitkey(1) & 0XFF
    if key == ord("q")
          break

    camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: You're missing a colon at the end of the `if key == ord("q")` line - all blocks are introduced by a colon in Python. If you want to record in .avi format you'll need to transcode the output (preferably on a faster machine); the Pi's camera firmware doesn't support it (probably because .avi doesn't officially support MPEG4 compression, not to mention it's an ancient format largely superseded at this point).

Comment: You might want to have a look at the script in [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/can-the-exposure-or-brightness-of-a-pi-cam-be-adjusted-without-interrupting-a-ru/26469#26469) as well which doesn't rely on OpenCV for keyboard handling; just uses curses (which is generally built into Python on Unix).

Answer (score 1):

Briefly looking into the [PiCamera documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#recording-video-to-a-file) (And with 0% knowledge in Python) I think you just may have a syntax error?

> syntax error: 'break' outside loop.

Basically you are trying to break (a loop) from a non looped code. Causing a syntax error. Or break is not allowed in that context.

I suggest the following psuedo code changes.

```
import time
import cv2   
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 360)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.start_recording('one_day.h264', quality=20, bitrate=750000)
    ///Above line will start recording. I dont think you explicilty need to use wait recording as its already recording on another thread.
    #camera.wait_recording(24 * 60 * 60)

    //Psuedo code here- I dont know Python
    ///start  a never ending loop, like while stop!= true?
    ///  use pause(50) to allow recording to progress
    ///  see if the user pressed a key in the buffer
    ///  Not sure if this is correct?    key = cv2.waitkey(1) & 0XFF
    ///    if key == ord("q")
    ///      exit your loop by setting stop = true (or break, since you are in a loop)
    ///  no key pressed, start the loop again until broken or another condition is met

    /// Now only call stop
    camera.stop_recording()
```

In the document it says using `pause()` will not raise errors. Only once you call stop recording. So it may result in half your video not being recorded. Maybe instead of `pause()` , use the `wait_recording` with a small time period (like 5 seconds?) If errors it *should* raise an error and tell you, instead of pretending to carry on and you only realising long time later.

I hope this helps, from a psuedo logical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If its all just a syntax error, it seems like you have break() outside of your if statement. It looks like you used 6 spaces while you should have used four.
You are also missing a colon at the end of the statement, making it an incomplete block.

So instead of this:

```
    if key == ord("q")
          break
```

Indent it with four spaces and use a colon.

```
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```